# elif conditional statement not working

Tags: linux, shell

I have this file as:

```
The number is %d0The number is %d1The number is %d2The number is %d3The number is %d4The number is %d5The number is %d6The...
The number is %d67The number is %d68The number is %d69The number is %d70The number is %d71The number is %d72The....
The number is %d117The number is %d118The number is %d119The number is %d120The number is %d121The number is %d122
```

I want to pad it like:

```
The number is %d0  The number is %d1  The number is %d2  The number is %d3  The number is %d4  The number is %d5  The number is %d6 
The number is %d63 The number is %d64 The number is %d65 The number is %d66 The number is %d67 The number is %d68 The number is %d69
d118The number is %d119The number is %d120The number is %d121The number is %d122The number is %d123The number is %d124The
```

Please tell me how to do it through shell script
I am working on Linux

Comment: By the way, you've got a backtick only in first alternative.

Comment: What shell are you using? bash?

Comment: Do you really have backtick in the second line?

Comment: I am not getting you. Plz explain what you want to say. I am new to shell scripting. My code may have many errors

Comment: Look at this character in the second line: ` - you only have one of them

Comment: this character isn't effecting the code it was written by mistake while pasting code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

This single command pipeline should do what you want:

```
sed 's/\(d[0-9]\+\)/\1   /g;s/\(d[0-9 ]\{3\}\) */\1/g' test2.txt >test3.txt
#                      ^ three spaces here
```

**Explanation:**

For each sequence of digits following a "d", add three spaces after it. (I'll use "X" to represent spaces.)

```
d1   becomes d1XXX
d10  becomes d10XXX
d100 becomes d100XXX
```

Now (the part after the semicolon), capture every "d" and the next three character which must be digits or spaces and output them but not any spaces beyond.

```
d1XXX   becomes d1XX
d10XXX  becomes d10X
d100XXX becomes d100
```

If you want to wrap the lines as you seem to show in your sample data, then do this instead:

```
sed 's/\(d[0-9]\+\)/\1   /g;s/\(d[0-9 ]\{3\}\) */\1/g' test2.txt | fold -w 133 >test3.txt
```

You may need to adjust the argument of the `fold` command to make it come out right.

There's no need for `if`, `grep`, loops, etc.

**Original answer:**

First of all, you really need to say which shell you're using, but since you have `elif` and `fi`, I'm assuming it's Bourne-derived.

Based on that assumption, your script makes no sense.

- The parentheses for the `if` and `elif` are unnecessary. In this context, they create a subshell which serves no purpose.
- The `sed` commands in the `if` and `elif` say "if the pattern is found, copy hold space (it's empty, by the way) to pattern space and output it and output all other lines.
- The first `sed` command will *always* be true so the `elif` will never be executed. `sed` always returns true unless there's an error.

This may be what you intended:

```
if grep -Eqs 'd[0-9]([^0-9]|$)' test2.txt; then
    sed 's/\(d[0-9]\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1  \2/g' test2.txt >test3.txt
elif grep -Eqs 'd[0-9][0-9]([^0-9]|$)' test2.txt; then
    sed 's/\(d[0-9][0-9]\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1 \2/g' test2.txt >test3.txt
else
    cat test2.txt >test3.txt
fi
```

But I wonder if all that could be replaced by something like this one-liner:

```
sed 's/\(d[0-9][0-9]?\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1 \2/g' test2.txt >test3.txt
```

Since I don't know what `test2.txt` looks like, part of this is only guessing.

Comment: grep doesn't work on this file, it gives error that I/P is too big

Comment: @Shweta: I don't know what "I/P" is. Have you tried the options I show for `grep` in my answer? You might be able to do: `if [ -n "$(sed -n '/foo/p' xaa)" ]; then`.

Comment: what this outer -n means is this an option

Comment: @Shweta: That means "true if the string is not empty". If the `sed` command finds a match, it will print the line containing the match so the test will be true. By the way, I meant to edit my test stuff out of that example command. This is what it should have looked like: `if [ -n "$(sed -n '/pattern/p' filename)" ]; then`.

Comment: @Shweta: Please edit your question and post the current version of your script. Please also tell me which shell you're using and its version and the operating system you're using.

Comment: what should I do if I want to recursively find out the no of [0-9] and add spaces accordingly. Please help. Your grep is working

Comment: @Shweta: I'm not sure I understand. Please show a couple of before and after examples.

Comment: if grep -Eqs 'd[0-9]([^0-9]|$)' test2.txt; then
    sed 's/\(d[0-9]\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1  \2/g' test2.txt >test3.txt
elif grep -Eqs 'd[0-9][0-9]([^0-9]|$)' test2.txt; then
    sed 's/\(d[0-9][0-9]\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1 \2/g' test2.txt >test3.txt
else
    cat test2.txt >test3.txt
fi
this is working fine, but what if I want to do this for upto 6 or 7 no.s. I want to implement it through loops. Is there any way and I am working in bourne shell

Comment: The file is : The no is %d0The no is %d1...%d10The no is say upto %d998The no is %d999. I want it to be like The no is %d0  (two spaces)The no is%d1  (same)...The no is %d10 (one space)upto %d998(no space)The no is %d999

Comment: sed 's/\\(d[0-9]{i}\\)\\([^0-9]\|$\\)/\1 {3-i}\2/g' test2.txt >test3.txt. Is this statement all right. Please reply

Comment: @Shweta: Oh, you want to pad the end of the number up to a certain width. No need for `if`, `else`, `grep`, looping, etc. It can probably be done with one `sed` script. Try this demo: `echo -e 'abcd1\nabcd10\nabcd100' | sed 's/\(d[0-9]\+\)/\1   /;s/\(d[0-9 ]\{3\}\) */\1x/'` (do the `echo` part without the `sed` part so you can see what it starts with).

Comment: @Shweta: No, that won't work. You can't have quantifiers on the right hand side of the substitute command.

Comment: @Shweta: Did you try the demo? **Please** edit your question (so you can properly format the information) and add some sample input data and what you want the output to look like. **Please?**.

Comment: Real big thanks for the answer. Please can you elaborate the command